# How can i get state value inside the slice.injectEndpoint in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to get the values from store because i store the token in the `state.userDetails` when logged In.

And in another slice i need to get the token

```
export const organizationApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getOrgInventory: builder.query({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `${ORGANIZATION_URL}/${id}/inventory`,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization:
            "Bearer GETTOKENHERE",
        },
      }),
      keepUnusedDataFor: 4,
    }),
  }),
});
```

How can i get the state inside this injectEndPoints?

My apiSlice was like this.

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["User", "Organization", "Inventory", 'Item'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read up on `fetchBaseQuery`'s `prepareHeaders`?

[Setting default headers on requests](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#setting-default-headers-on-requests). That's the intended place to do that, not in every single `query`.

```
import { fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import type { RootState } from './store'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: '/',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token

    // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }

    return headers
  },
})
```